# Regex for particular given range "001 to 150"

Tags: regex

Here is what I have tried
but unable get a desired result.
Case1:

```
^(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-5][0-9])$
```

it is accepting ranges from 001-159 as I have give [0-9]

For Case2:

```
^(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-50][0])$
```

it is accepting 110, 120... and 150 as last accepted digit is "0".

The Desired Result should only accept 001-150
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: ^(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$

Comment: For most circumstances, I would **not do with this with a regex**. Something along the lines of: `length(x) == 3 && Integer(x) >= 1 && Integer(x) <= 150` is *much* easier to understand. (The exact code, of course, depends of your programming language.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all possible, try to parse those as integers and do the range check in the programming language of your choice.

Other than that, your first approach was close, just restrict the 3rd alternation to 149 and add 150 as separate value, like

```
^(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$
```

Comment: This allows `000`, which should be excluded. You need first two alternations from OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^(00[1-9])|(0[1-9]\d)|(1[0-4]\d)|(150)$
```

which will match:

- 00 followed by 1-9
- 0 followed by 1-9 followed by any digit
- 1 followed by 0-4 and any digit
- or 150

The groups are mutually exclusive, so only one should ever match, if any.